# How to declare and use modules, controllers, services and bootstrap manually in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-bootstrap

i'm trying to build an AngularJS app that has one Controller, one Service and that Bootstraps manually (no `ng-app`). The problem is that I keep having an error :

> Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got string

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="inc/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="inc/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="inc/services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppController">
        [...]
    </body>
</html>
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['htmlControllerApp']);
});
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('htmlControllerApp', [])
.controller('AppController', 'ConnectionService', ['$scope', function ($scope, ConnectionService) {
    // Code
}]);
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('htmlControllerApp')
.factory('ConnectionService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    // Code
}]);
```

Thanks

---

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

In **controllers.js**, use instead :

```
angular.module('htmlControllerApp')
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'ConnectionService', function ($scope, ConnectionService) {
    // Code
}]);
```

In **bootstrap.js**, as a "good practice" :

```
angular.module('htmlControllerApp', []);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['htmlControllerApp']);
});
```

This will create the module just once in **bootstrap.js** and AngularJS will try to retrieve it in **controllers.js** and **services.js**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the page you're looking for.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

and change this

```
angular.module('htmlControllerApp', [])
  .controller('AppController', 'ConnectionService', ['$scope', function ($scope,     ConnectionService) {
    // Code
}]);
```

to this ->

```
angular.module('htmlControllerApp', [])
  .controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'ConnectionService', function ($scope, ConnectionService) {
    // Code
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I misplaced the 'ConnectionService' attribute

Comment: @A.Gille no problem. don't forget to reward it with a nice 'accept the solution' click, so I will get nice points for this :)